# Saving a new jbpm process in guvnor causes it to be lost

Tags: jbpm, drools-guvnor

Using jbpm designer 2.4 in Guvnor 5.5.0. I create a new JBPM 2.0 diagram, edit it, and then when I try to save it, it says "Saving" then "Refreshing Package Data", then something else, and then my diagram disappears. I bet it's some kind of config issue. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?
I am hosting the two in Jboss AS7 with all the defaults, except guvnor is running under

```
> http://localhost:8080/guvnor
```

instead of

```
> http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor
```

Thanks!
Yuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated the designer configuration file with the new URL from guvnor, as described here?
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.designer.html#d0e4389

Kris